# How do I get the previous XElement sibling with matching conditions

Tags: c#, performance, linq, xelement, siblings

I've got some data that comes in XML format, and which contains a list of items:

```
<message>
    <items id="_DD" value="28OCT"/>
    <items id="_PC" value="ABV"/>
    <items id="_CT" value="15H03"/>
    <items id="_CD" value="31OCT"/>
    <items id="_AN" value="5556695"/>
    <items id="_CC" value="PSD"/>
    <items id="_MK" value="OJJ"/>
    <items id="_DT" value="LKM"/>
    <items id="_IT" value="B239"/>
    <items id="_ML" value="4569"/>
    <items id="_TA" value=""/>
    <items id="_P1" value=""/>
    <items id="_MK" value="APK"/>
    <items id="_DT" value="MMK"/>
    <items id="_IT" value="B219"/>
    <items id="_ML" value="0069"/>
    <items id="_RC" value="0"/>
    ...
</message>
```

Most of the items are independent between them, but there can be cases in which they are related. For example, the `id="_MK"` items mark a new category.

So I need to make a list of elements (with `id="_ML"`, for example) and be able to get, also, the category to which they belong (which is the value of the previous item with `id="_MK"`).

**How do I get the value, for each item, of their previous `id="_MK"` sibling, so I can assign the category (the value of that `id="_MK"` item) to them?**

In the case of the `"_ML"` list, the result should contain:

```
[
    {
        value: "4569",
        category: "OJJ"
    },
    {
        value: "0069",
        category: "APK"
    }
]
```

I know I could do this with a `foreach`, but the list of items is quite large and **I'm worried about performance**. I haven't been able to find any solution using LinQ, which was my best option in mind.

*Also, the format and structure comes from a third party source, so I cannot change it.*

Comment: What is the logic behind parent(`_MK`) and child(`_ML`) relation? For example does `_CC` and `_CD` items related?

Comment: It's not a parent-child relationship. It's more a complementary information for some specific items. The `_MK` and `_ML` is just an example. The `_CC` and `_CD` are not related between them and, in this case, as there is no `_MK` before them, they would be independent. However, the `_MK` was just a sample.